# Scala: implicits, subclassing and member types

Tags: scala

Lets say we want to use type classes to implement pretty printing:

```
trait Printer[T] {def print(t: T)}
```

with default implementation for ints:

```
implicit object IntPrinter extends Printer[Int] {
    override def print(i : Int): Unit = println(i)
}
```

Our specific types we want to print are:

```
trait Foo {
    type K
    val k: K
}

class IntFoo extends Foo {
    override type K = Int
    override val k = 123
}
```

cool. Now I want to build printers for all Foos with printable Ks

```
implicit def fooPrinter[FP <: Foo](implicit ev: Printer[FP#K]): Printer[FP] =
    new Printer[FP] {
        override def print(f: FP): Unit = {
            Predef.print("Foo: ")
            ev.print(f.k)
        }
    }
```

lets check that implicits are resolved:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    implicitly[Printer[Int]]
    implicitly[Printer[IntFoo]]
}
```

scalac 2.11.2 says:

```
diverging implicit expansion for type Sandbox.Printer[Int]
    starting with method fooPrinter in object Sandbox
        implicitly[Printer[Int]]
```

whaat?

OK, lets rewrite fooPrinter:

```
implicit def fooPrinter[KP, FP <: Foo {type K = KP}](implicit ev: Printer[KP]) =
    new Printer[FP] {
        override def print(f: FP): Unit = {
            Predef.print("Foo: ")
            ev.print(f.k)
        }
    }
```

this works in 2.11, but what's the problem with the first approach?
Unfortunately we're on 2.10, and second solution still doesn't work. It compiles until we add one more sime printer like

```
implicit object StringPrinter extends Printer[String] {
    override def print(s : String): Unit = println(s)
}
```

and it mysteriously breaks Printer[IntFoo] implicit:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter e:   
    Sandbox.Printer[Sandbox.IntFoo]
```

compiler bugs?

Answer (score 2):

Order of implicit declarations matters. In your source code reorder original code from

```
implicit object IntPrinter ...
...
implicit def fooPrinter ...
```

to

```
implicit def fooPrinter ...
...
implicit object IntPrinter ...
```

Comment: moving it fixes the first definition of fooPrinter on 2.11 (and causes really strange bugs on 2.10). Any explanation of why do they clash if the order is different?

Comment: My view on implicit is that if there is even a little doubt then it simply doesn't work. It is by design paranoid so that it doesn't accidentaly resolve something that you might not expect ... but that doesn't answer your question. I would assume that the compiler has found an implicit definition Printer[FP] that might possibly return Printer[Int] just by looking at its return value. At this point it probably doesn't check the FP <: Foo restriction. And then it finds another implicit definition for Printer[Int]. And that's the error. But that's only my theory.

Comment: One more reason why implicit resolution is so fragile is also compilation speed. As you can imagine it can become an exponential backtracking nightmare if it would really try to evaluate all possible implicit definitions. But transparency is probably more important.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but should be linear since compiler isn't trying all *combinations* of implicits. And yes, I think correctness and transparency should be a priority over compilation speed :)

Comment: You're right probably, it depends on how clever the algorithm would be. But anyway the compiler definitely doesn't really try all possible combinations. So there are definitely cases where implict resolution "should" work just by looking at the code, but it doesn't because of those paranoid rules.